# Pass a parameter to a function from bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a user profile screen that I use to either add a new user or edit the current user.

I want to pass a parameter based on whether or not the user is a new user. The parameter is isNewUser and is a bool.

I have 2 ways to access the user_profile_screen:

1. is from a side drawer where I pass "true"
2. is from the bottom navigation bar where I want to pass "false"

Here is the code for both methods:

```
class MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  int _pageIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> appScreens = [
    const CompanyDashboardScreen(),
    const TransactionDetailScreen(true),
    const AppointmentCalendarScreen(),
    const UserProfileScreen(),
    const ChatScreen(),
  ];

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await auth.signOut();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const CustomAppBar(),
      body: Container(child: appScreens[_pageIndex]),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: (ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            const UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName: Text('Billy Bob Baker'),
              accountEmail: Text('billy.bob.baker@gmail.com'),
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Add Company'),
                  selected: _pageIndex == 5,
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const CompanyScreen(true)));
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Add User'),
                  selected: _pageIndex == 6,
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                const UserProfileScreen(true)));
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Log Out'),
                  selected: _pageIndex == 7,
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    signOut();
                    // Then close the drawer
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()));
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black45,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _pageIndex,
        onTap: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _pageIndex = value;
          });
        },
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add_business_outlined), label: "Trxn"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), label: "Calendar"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.people), label: "User"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), label: 'Chat'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // Added this for BottomNavigationBar sync
  void setIndex(int index) {
    if (mounted) setState(() => _pageIndex = index);
  }
}
```

For the side drawer, I can pass "true" in the function call but how do I do this in the bottom navigation bar?

Here is the widget class for the user_profile_screen:

```
class UserProfileScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'user_profile_screen';
  final Users? users;
  final bool isNewUser;

  const UserProfileScreen([this.isNewUser = true, this.users]);

  @override
  ConsumerState<UserProfileScreen> createState() => _UserProfileScreenState();
}
```

I am using a default value for isNewUser but how do I pass the value of "false" from the bottom navigation bar?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, In the `onTap` of the `BottomNavigationBar` (which you're already using) check if the passed-in index is the one you want, and then navigate to the `UserProfileScreen`:

```dart
Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(onTap: (index)      {
        if (index == 0) { // or whatever index you are looking for
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserProfileScreen(false)),
          );
        }
      },
```

Comment: That was too easy. Thank you so much